# change the elements in the wp menu

Tags: wordpress

how can I change the element structure of the menu in wordpress themes? like I want to change the structure into this:

```
<nav id="mymenu" class="menu"> <!-- here the li tags with links --></nav>
```

just want to replace the UL tags with the nav tags which is html5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the items_wrap parameter in wp_nav_menu to achieve this.

There is an example in this page

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

under the heading "Removing the ul wrap"

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that you wouldn't want to use `<li></li>` elements outside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element - it's not valid HTML. What you probably want to do is wrap the list in a nav tag.

I'm assuming, since you're asking this question, that you're using WP's auto-generated menu? You can change a bunch of variables - check the WordPress Codex (always): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu